# Can we somehow measure the strength of an entanglement?

Tags: entanglement

If I have a list of qubits, is there any formula how to calculate the strength of their entanglement? Something like a correlation coefficient.

Comment: It's not clear for me from the post, what is the formula for the 'entanglement coefficient', I would expect something like these are the inputs and this is the how the output is calculated.

Comment: Please clarify, since the word "coefficient" doesn't seem to appear anywhere in your question or the one linked in my first comment.

Comment: In my mind, quantifying entanglement for a multipartite system is seldom the same as quantifying a single correlation coefficient.

Comment: Hi! Here's another question @user1271772 found that might be of use - [How to measure entanglement in an algorithm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/how-to-measure-entanglement-in-an-algorithm)